# Is it possible in a UITabBarController to have one tab in a fixed position and able reorder the other tabs?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I would like for one tab in a UITabBarController to have a fixed position and the user can reorganize the other tabs however they like. I have the UITabBarController > UINavigationController > UITableViewController setup.

Is this possible?

UPDATE:

The following code, in applicationDidFinishLaunching, is what I'm using and it doesn't work. I'm trying to get a reference to the SavedTableViewController, I think that's the problem. Any ideas?

```
NSMutableArray *customizableVCs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tabBarController.customizableViewControllers];
    for (id controller in tabBarController.customizableViewControllers){
            if ([controller isKindOfClass:[SavedTableViewController class]]){
                NSLog(@"Removing Object");
                [customizableVCs removeObject:controller];
            }
    }
    tabBarController.customizableViewControllers = customizableVCs;
```

UPDATE 2:

This is the code that worked for me. I had to put the snippet below adding the tabBarController to the window.

```
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [self setTabOrderIfSaved];

    NSMutableArray *customizableViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tabBarController.customizableViewControllers];
    [customizableViewControllers removeObject:savedNavigationController];
    tabBarController.customizableViewControllers = customizableViewControllers;
```

Comment: When you say that it doesn't work, what exactly are you referring to? Does the initial state of customizableViewControllers match what you expect?

Comment: I think it's this line that's not working...  if ([controller isKindOfClass:[SavedTableViewController class]]){

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the view controller corresponding to that tab from the [`customizableViewControllers` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006931-CH3-SW11) of your tab bar controller. Assuming that you want fixedViewController to remain fixed:

```
NSMutableArray *customizableViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tabBarController.customizableViewControllers];
[customizableViewControllers removeObject:fixedViewController];
tabBarController.customizableViewControllers = customizableViewControllers;
```

Because `customizableViewControllers` is reinitialized when the `viewControllers` property is changed, you should do this after the rest of your tab bar controller’s state has been set up.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this. There probably isn't, but is there a way to make a tab stay in the tabBar if it is moved? I don't mind of a viewController is moved around in the bar, I just don't want it to move to the "More" section.

Comment: Does it matter that the setup I have is tabBarController > navController > viewController?

Comment: @W Dyson—No, the setup pretty much doesn't matter. You should note, though, that `viewController` isn't actually in the tab bar's controller array; the one you should be removing from its `customizableViewControllers` is `navController`, i.e. `viewController`'s parent, as that's the one that you've actually added to it.